# height of the house above the hill(can't sketch !)

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Problem : A house is constructed on a hill . From a point on the line of the greatest slope of the hill and at 7m from the base of the house , a man found that the measure of the angle opposite to the house is 40 degree , when the man walked 5m away opposite to the house become 26 degree . 
Find the height of the house above the hill ?

I need help to sketch the problem because i don't understand the visualization of this problem ,
Also what is the meaning of this sentence "From a point on the line of the greatest slope of the hill " ?

Comment: If you are being asked for the height of the house, the angle measures may be angles of elevation to the roof.  The wording is not clear.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes the wording of this problem is not clear , I can't sketch the problem well  also this sentence is not clear " "From a point on the line of the greatest slope of the hill "